# Yii2 SQL query grouping OR with AND

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Good day.

I am relatively new to yii2.

What am I trying is this sort of SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a=1 AND (b=1 OR b=2)
```

How do I write such query via yii2 query builder?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. please add what you tried so far.

Comment: try this link-->http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/select-query-model/#select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `orWhere()` , `andWhere()` and `where()` functions.

the `"or"` and `"and"` words are the type of union it made with all the previous `where` conditions

so, this query:

```
Table::find()->where('b=1')->orWhere('b=2')->andWhere('a=1')->all();
```

Make something like this:

```
select * from Table where (((b=1) or b=2) and a=1)
```

The `all()` function tell yii2 to select al records its founds

Note: this code dont work, its just and example.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done like this:

```
$model = User::find()
        ->where('a = :a', [':a' => 1])
        ->andWhere('b = :b1 or b = :b2', [':b1' => 1, ':b2'=> 2])
        ->all();
```